# site not loading properly after adding ssl certificate

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl, https

[image]we are trying to add a ssl certificate for magento site.

we we are following this link:

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

I did "base secure url to start with https ", means

in system->configuration->web, i changed http://demosite.com to

https://demosite.com

but than site is not loading properly, seems css and js is not loading properly as like in following image

http://prntscr.com/86spu6

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you change the base secure urls for media, skin and js to point to `https`.
Maybe your page is not loading the resources because they are not on https.
A link to your page would help

Comment: we will try this.....

Comment: as I mentioned, you resources are loaded via http. did you clear the cache?

Comment: please add your comment as answer......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments....
Make sure you change the base secure urls for media, skin and js to point to https. Maybe your page is not loading the resources because they are not on https.  And clear the cache.

Comment: how  to make the cart page secure ? means http://sitename/checkout/cart/

to https ://sitename/checkout/cart/

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 add in the `config.xml` file of any of your modules inside the `frontend` tag this `<secure_url>checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart></secure_url>`

Comment: for this, i used some module @Marius , after that "add to cart" button did't worked.

thanks now its fine.

Answer (score 1):

All your http changed to https specially css file. Open your site browser and find link http/https.
you may also add below code at following head.phtml

```
app\design\frontend\yourthemepack\default\template\page\html\head.phtml

if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] )  && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ) {
    $http = 'https';
}
 else {
    $http = 'http';
}
```