# Add to cart ajax buttons not working with secure(https) cart

Tags: addtocart, https, secure

we added secure url to entire site by follwoing this link :

[site not loading properly after adding ssl certificate](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79354/site-not-loading-properly-after-adding-ssl-certificate/79361?noredirect=1#comment104915_79361)

than we added secure url https to cart page by following link :

http://magento.dijksterhuis.org/securing-the-magento-shopping-cart-with-https/

i added following code in config.xml [ http://pastebin.com/HaLDM4Qn ]

under

after this add to cart button is not working .

please check the site :

http://videomergerapp.com/learners-play-number-picture-knob-puzzle.html

i followed this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692029/magento-add-to-cart-ajax-buttons-not-working-with-securehttps-cart

but i did't got what code need to be edited for our theme.

this is our view.phtml :

http://pastebin.com/4R3ht5yg

Comment: For you add to cart post or get request might be going through http://yourdomain.com/..... Change it to https:// it will work for you.

Comment: yes, its working with htttps but not with http, but our client dont want https on product page.

Comment: Then based on the http:// or https:// on your page you have to make the add to cart link dynamic. If you can provide the code in your question, you may get help.

Comment: please check the updated question.

Comment: This is blocked in my organisation

Comment: are you telling pastebin is blocked ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27458/discussion-between-muk-and-baby-in-magento-2).